# how to check if Google Play Services is up to date

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my app I need to use how Google Play Services , so at first I must check if Google Play Services is available in user's phone

This is what I've tried :

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getApplicationContext() );
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //alarm to go and install Google Play Services
}
```

after that if it's installed , I need to check Google Play Services version on the user's phone is up to date or not
how can I do it ??
any idea ?

Comment: Have a look here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737632/how-to-check-google-play-services-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check reference from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context))

it will show you **isGooglePlayServicesAvailable** will return code, and the on of that code is **SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED**

so you can do something like these

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( getApplicationContext() );
if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    //alarm to go and install Google Play Services
}else if(status == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED){
   Toast.makeText(context,"please udpate your google play service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show
}
```

Comment: when status will be ""update_required" ?

Comment: @FariborZ when the version of google play user different from play service from android SDK

Comment: This method was deprecated. you can check your reference.

Comment: Does `status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` indicate Google Play Services is not installed?