# android - Cannot find Google play services package name

Tags: android

While running my app I'm getting this error in my logcat -

```
Cannot find Google Play services package name.
```

I've tried deleting google play services package and re-installing it but its still the same.

Is there any solution for this ? Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Google Play services version?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737632/how-to-check-google-play-services-version)

Answer (score 1):

The fix is included in Google Play services 9.4.0.  Make sure to recompile your app against v9.4 and let me know if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- Have you [added it to the build](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) and does it match your installed version.
- Does the physical device you are testing on have the [Play Services APK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) installed.
- Is the virtual device (AVD) a Google APIs system image (Android 4.4.2+).

Comment: I've added it to the build.
I'm using emulator with API 23