# Android : How to check google play service version for mobile vision api

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing an application and using Mobile Vision Api for text recognizing.I noticed that its not working in some devices.After searched I understand that one reason is because of google play service version that is installed on device.So how can I check the google play service version that is installed on user device?
And what is the minimum google play service version that this api could work?

Comment: Did my answer provide what you're looking for in this question?

Comment: OP asked for a way to check the PlayServices version on a user's device.Your answer should leave out the manual check. Also, the "minimum Android version" is not what he's looking for. It's the "minimum PlayServices version"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for checking version

> GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE

I think, first you should check, if service is available ?

> public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)

[Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29)

Answer (score 0):

**How to know GPS version of your phone?**

If manually, go to Settings > Applications > Google Play Services.

If programatically, follow the answer in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737632/how-to-check-google-play-services-version):

```
int v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms", 0 ).versionCode;
```

**What is the minimum google play service version for this API?**

Minimum Android version required is [Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/getting-started).