# android : The minimum google play service version for mobile vision ocr?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing an application and using Mobile Vision Api for text recognizing.I noticed that its not working in some devices.After searched I understand that one reason is because of google play service version that is installed on user device.So I know that I can get the version that is installed on user device like this :

```
int v = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms", 0 ).versionCode;
```

but what is the minimum version that i have to check on user device to notice to the user to update the google play service on device(if necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is related to your [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187956/android-how-to-check-google-play-service-version-for-mobile-vision-api).

There seems to be no minimum GPS version specified from the [Overview of Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview) however it is recommended you update to the lastest as:

> Google Play services gives you the freedom to use the newest APIs for
>   popular Google services without worrying about device support. Updates
>   to Google Play services are distributed automatically by the Google
>   Play Store and new versions of the client library are delivered
>   through the Android SDK Manager. This makes it easy for you to focus
>   on what's important: your users' experience.