# How to make firebase backwards compatible with previous play services versions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play-services

I have integrated Firebase into the app that I'm making. Problem is, a lot of phones I've tried this on have older play services versions and so the app simply does not work without them updating. Is there a way that I can make my app backwards compatible without having to update? Maybe by decreasing the version? My app uses Firebase auth `11.8.0` to authenticate, Firebase storage and Firebase Realtime database. Also, whats the minimum play services version that I can use without losing functionality?

Comment: Its better to use the latest play services version, checking the device play service version and display a dialog message to update the play services is a better method. To find play service version, refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737632/how-to-check-google-play-services-version

Comment: Okay heres the thing... the audience I'm targeting with this app will not update because were a third world country. So, what is the minimum possible play services I can use while not losing any functionality?

Comment: Firebase does not support devices that are incapable of self-updating their version Play Services.