# Notify the user to update Google Play Service

Tags: android, firebase

I would like your help on something, I'm developing an app using firebase, so it works and needs google play services relatively up-to-date. In my tests, in outdated versions the crash app. I some applications when it is necessary a certain version of google play service appears a notification requesting the user to update google play service, this is my doubt, how do I make this message appear?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
final GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
final int status = googleApiAvailability .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { 
    //Status that you are interested is SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED
    final Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this,status, 1);
    dialog.show();
}
```

**Note:**

`GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)` has been deprecated.

Comment: @PriyankPatel you can get value of `GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE` which returns, client library version

Comment: @Sagar Thanks for the reply, this code worked almost as I want, the only problem is that when I click on the message to update google play service nothing happens, I need to do something else to redirect the user?

Comment: @DouglasNickson Ideally you dont need to do anythig. By clicking ot it, itwill direct l to the Play Store if Google Play services is out of date or missing, or to system settings if Google Play services is disabled on the device

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to do that. Look at below code

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            // Handle 1

            // Show own dialog for status
            if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED) {
                // This is the case, where update required for google play service
            } else {
                // This would be case like, play services not available on device and needs to install
            }

            // Handle 2

            // Or you can depend on library classes to handle these eror and show appropriate error message with action in dialog.
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // Unrecoverable error.
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

In above code `// Handle 1` and `// Handle 2` are two ways of doing that. In most of the cases `// Handle 2` is better option. For more error handling in you want (not related to this question), you should read [How to check Google Play services version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737632/how-to-check-google-play-services-version)

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {
    final int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Log.e(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));

        // need to update google play services.
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 1);
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(status));
        // google play services is updated. 
        return true;
    }
}
```

try with this.

Comment: Isn't this deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can check version using below code of [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE)

```
GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE
```

First you need to check, if Google play service available or not using below API.

```
public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context)
```

**OR**

You can directly check using below API.

```
public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Context context, int minApkVersion)
```

> Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this
>   device, and that the version installed on this device is **no older than**
>   the one **required by this client** or
>   **specified in minApkVersion**.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check for play service availablity
int available=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if(available!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
     if(available== ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED){
        Toast.makeText(this,"please update your google play service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "please download the google play service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```